# Should I re-lock bootloader after flashing developer preview on nexus 5?

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5, bootloader-lock

I have flashed the Android M developer preview 3 on my Nexus 5 phone, for which I was required to unlock the bootloader. Now that the flashing has completed successfully, should I re-lock my bootloader? I had seen threads on xda siting that phones could get into boot-loop if bootloader is locked after flashing. I have no custom recoveries installed or the system is "as is" received from google. So do I relock or will it soft brick my phone? I am only a noob. Please be detailed.

Comment: Come on, no answers? Where are you guys?

Comment: Nobody is answering? That's weird.

Comment: AFAIK, in general, you can safely relock the bootloader, but you will need to unlock it again to flash/root. I haven't tried relocking the bootloader, but I guess since you're using developer preview, relocking it might be bad. Just wait until Android release the final version of Android 6.0, flash it and relock the bootloader if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take a risk until stable version of android M is released. And you also want to recover it to your original firmware. locking-bootloader will make it difficult for you!

Comment: I keep nothing on my phone that I cannot afford to loose. So regarding wipe when unlocking bootloader, I can wipe it anytime. Only thing is, it must not brick my device.

Comment: Yep, It can brick your phone and will loose your phone.

Comment: I hope this answers your question.